# Getting black screen when I load next video dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change videos dynamically in my web page using JavaScript. The first video (.mp4 format) file is playing well, but when I click the button to change the video, it is showing some black screen instead of playing next video.

I tried in many ways to solve this issue by reading many Stack Overflow articles, but it is still not working.

Could anyone please guide me to solve this issue?

My JavaScript code:

```
function vidSwap() {
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    player.pause();
    document.getElementById("webm").src = "D:\movies\Telugu\movie2.webm";
    document.getElementById("mp4").src = "D:\movies\Telugu\movie2.mp4";
    document.getElementById("ogg_src").src = "D:\movies\Telugu\movie2.ogg";
    player.load();
    player.play();
}
```

My HTML Code:

```
<video id="player" height="380" width="440" controls>
    <source id="webm" src="D:\movies\Telugu\movie1.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source id="mp4" src="D:\movies\Telugu\movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source id="ogg_src" src="D:\movies\Telugu\movie1.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Next Video Clip" onclick="vidSwap()" />
```

Comment: As @hatchet mentioned, it feels like a src set attrib issue. Because, you are setting directly from win directory. I tried using just MP4 (cdn) and seems fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2n3g9fh3/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `vidSwap` function: When you're setting the `src` attribute of each of the elements, the backslashes in the strings you're using are being interpreted as escaped characters.

```
document.getElementById("webm").src = "D:\movies\Telugu\movie2.webm";
//                                       ^^     ^^     ^^
```

You need to escape the backslash characters by adding an extra backslash before each (`\\`), like so:

```
document.getElementById("webm").src = "D:\\movies\\Telugu\\movie2.webm";
// Repeat for each string
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @Varun If you feel my answer would be helpful to others, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer (me) and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.